# Swift Side menu swipe to open

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a simple sliding menu on my app but I don't know the right way to open it with a pan gesture.

[image]

I have it set up on the storyboard and I open it as modal with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` for the opening and closing transitions I also use `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` for closing with a gesture.

To open the menu with a gesture I added a pan gesture to the main view but how do I instantiate the menu with a swipe and then continue the animation to open?

I tried to instantiate the menu when the swipe starts and passed the gesture to the menu controller so I can keep track of the pan position but this seems glitchy.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `UIViewController`? Why not just have it as a `UIView` and animate that?

Comment: Because I will need to add more functionality to the menu that will require to be a controller. But if I can't find a solution that's my next move.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the functionality that compels it to be a `UIViewController` ?

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/MKLEGYDrawerLayout you have a pod for that